# HTML, CSS, Bootstrap :: Media Queries aren't applying how I think they should

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and am still fairly new to web programming in general.

I programmed a part of my page that works great. However, I didn't prepare well enough for smaller devices. I have the height of what I am working on set at 400px. However, when I use a phone, it gets too horizontally squished, so I just made it so half of it wraps down to the bottom.

However, the size is still set at 400px, so it messes a whole bunch of things up. The easiest way of fixing this would be when the screen is `md` or larger, set height to 400px, when it is smaller than that, set height to 800px.

I searched around the web for solution and I found that media queries should be able to do this.

This is what I had previously, the height is always set at 400px

```
.addon {height:400px;}
```

This of course sets the height to 400px and works like I want when the screen is `md` or larger.

---

This is my attempt at what I am trying to do.

```
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) 
{
    .addon {height:400px;}
}

@media (max-width: @screen-sm-max)
{
    .addon {height:800px}
}
```

Absolutely nothing happens with this code. Neither of the two heights get applied no matter what size the screen is.

According to what I have read and seen online, I feel like this should work.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you try with something else then `height`?  for example `color: #1af;` and see what happens.  (change in height is only visible when there is enough text in it to get to these 400px)

Comment: I tried it with multiple attributes with none of them being added. When I inspect element with chrome, it doesn't show any of the CSS inside the queries being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, using the variables `@screen-md-min` and `@screen-sm-max` are LESS variables, which I am not using. Replacing those with actual pixel values works. So this is the working code.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) 
{
    .addon {height:400px;}
}

@media (max-width: 991px)
{
    .addon {height:800px}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using twitter bootstrap classes like col-xx-12 which divides the container where it is applied in 12 columns and will automatically change the size when the screen is resized. However it will not work if you don't apply the view-port = 1.0 meta tag

Comment: But if you notice his css, he isn't trying to change the width automatically, but the height.